# c# string manipulation add * for plain word

Tags: c#, regex, split

I would to like to achieve the following thing in best possible way in c#, can someone help me.

I have string something like

```
ind item1 +china -brazil "my component" "my country":india type:project
```

I want to convert it as below.

```
ind* item1*  +china -brazil "my component" "my country":india type:project
```

In simple terms, if the word doesn't have anything like `+`, `-` or `:` or double quote I want to add `*` at the end. Please help me.

Comment: Are these strings always going to include the same words/format? i.e. will they always start with `ind item`?

Comment: no..its will be user entered one...its kind of search keyword input.

Comment: Are you trying to do this to add wildcards for searching?

Comment: yes, for simple word I want wildcard search..if it is kind of expression no need to add wild card

Comment: Are you searching a SQL database with this? You can do the wildcard searching in the database layer rather than on the front end

Comment: I am using ElasticSearch as search engine, connecting ES through NEST ..as mentioned in above string , most of them are outofbox from ES(like - for exclude , double quotes for exact match and : for search on column) on top of that I want wild card search for simple words..anywayz I achieved it with little lengthy code...not sure if any simplest way to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some how I achieved it in lengthy way ...Not sure if any shortcut is there to achieve...

var keywords_updated = (keywords.Replace(" ", "* "));
            keywords_updated = keywords_updated.EndsWith("*") ? keywords_updated : keywords_updated + "*";
            MatchCollection col = Regex.Matches(keywords, "\\"(.*?)\\"");//Regex.Matches(keywords, "(?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\")|[^\" ]+");
            var data = col.Cast().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();

```
        Console.WriteLine(data.Count);
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            keywords_updated = keywords_updated.Replace(item.Replace(" ","* "),item);
        }
        keywords_updated = keywords_updated.Replace("\"*", "\" ");
        var spllist = new List<string> { "-", "+", ":" };
        var words = keywords_updated.Split(' ').Where(x=>x.StartsWith("-")||x.StartsWith("+")||x.Contains(":"));
        foreach(var word in words)
        {
            keywords_updated = keywords_updated.Replace(word, word.Replace("*",""));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(keywords_updated);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the split string into words has all the characters as letter. Here is an example:

```
    string AddStars(string input)
    {
        var words = input.Split(' ');

        var output = "";
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            output += word;
            if (!word.ToCharArray().ToList().All(char.IsLetter))
                output += "*";

            output += " ";
        }

        return output.TrimEnd();
    }
```

Comment: the problem is this will not cover double quoted word.

Comment: @srikanthkadem I know, I could add the code for double quoted word, but I don't have the time right now. This is meant to be a starting point for you.